# PHP Как отправить почту ассинхронно?

Tags: php, yii2

PHP Как отправить почту в ассинхронном режиме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cоздайте [консольную команду](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html) которая будет отправлять сообщение.
Вызываете ее асинхронно с помощью ниже приведенного кода:

```
 /**
  * Проверяем является ли текущая ос windows
  * @return bool
  */
 function isWindows(){
     return (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows");
 }

 // Путь к входящему файлу для консольных команд 
 $path = 'path/console.php';
 // Команда для выполнения
 $command = '<route> [--option1=value1 --option2=value2 ... argument1 argument2 ...]';

 // Собираем все в единое целое
 $cmd = "php -f {$path} {command}";

 if (isWindows()) {
    // Запускаем под windows
    pclose(popen("start /b {$cmd}", 'w'));
 } else { //*nix
    // Запускаем под linux
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &", $output);
 }
```

**Дополнение**

Более интересный вариант можно сделать с использованием **GEARMAN**

**Вариант для хостинга**

Можно регистрировать отправки сообщений в базе и по крону каждые 5 минут вызывать тот же консольный скрипт для отправки писем **без exec и popen**

Comment: Это серьезно работает? Просто я читал много разной информации, но такого ни разу не видел.

Comment: Я не уверен что на хостинге эти команды будут работать. для линукса.

Comment: Будет работать. Насчет хостинга не уверен. Более сложный вариант это настроить на сервере Gearman и Supervisor.

Comment: Еще вариант с кроном есть

Comment: Немного обновил ответ

Comment: По вашему варианту может быть  уязвимость. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540651/making-phps-mail-asynchronous

Comment: Крон конечно хорошо, но хотелось бы без крона.

Comment: Gearman и Supervisor.- на хостинге это не настроишь.

Comment: Мне каждую минуту нужно будет крон вызывать... Не много ли?

Comment: Не вижу в этом никаких проблем. Одни запрос к базе в минуту, по вашему это много?

Comment: По поводу уязвимости, думаю есть вероятность только если в коде будут использоваться пользовательские данные, иначе если код сугубо внутренний то очень сложно будет что-то провернуть.

Comment: Решение с fastcgi_finish_request() на хостинге не работает?

Comment: fastcgi_finish_request() - На хостинге пока не пробовал, на локальном веб-сервере работает как то не так, сюдя по всему ответ.

Comment: fastcgi_finish_request() - не работает на хостинге